# Finding intervals in a table

Tags: mysql

Here is the problem. I have a table with diffrent processes and their states with state timestamp. For example. Process with id  135 had state 1 at this time "2014-01-09 15:41:22".
There are 4 state types 0 = OK 1 = Warning 2 = Critical 3 = Unknown. Here is a fragment of the table:

```
id   state_time          process_id state
37  "2014-01-09 15:41:22"   135     1
92  "2014-01-09 15:42:01"   135     0
153 "2014-01-09 15:46:28"   135     1
204 "2014-01-09 15:47:25"   135     0
259 "2014-02-05 14:48:00"   135     1
321 "2014-02-05 14:49:20"   135     2
352 "2014-02-05 14:50:40"   135     2
383 "2014-02-05 14:52:00"   135     1
464 "2014-02-05 14:53:20"   135     2
576 "2014-02-05 14:54:40"   135     2
621 "2014-02-05 14:56:00"   135     2
666 "2014-02-05 14:57:20"   135     1
747 "2014-02-05 14:58:40"   135     3
792 "2014-02-05 15:00:07"   135     1
957 "2014-02-05 15:18:53"   135     0
```

Here i selected only one process, but there can be a lot of them. So as you can see in first row this process in Warning state on the next row he becomes OK. So thats mean that in interval between 15:41:22 and 15:42:01 it was in warning state. And then again Warning state and so on. So here we can find 6 Warning intervals, 2 Critical and 1 Unknown.
The task is to calculate how long process was in each state in certain period of time.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is the `lead()` function, but MySQL doesn't support that.  To get the next time, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select state_time
        from atable t2
        where t2.process_id = t.process_id and
              t2.state_time > t.state_time and
              t2.state <> t.state
       ) as next_state_time
from atable t;
```

For performance, you will want an index on `atable(process_id, state_time, state)`.

The next problem is to aggregate the times.  Here is one method:

```
select process_id, state,
       sum(timestampdiff(second, state_time, next_state_time)) as seconds
from (select t.*,
             (select state_time
              from atable t2
              where t2.process_id = t.process_id and
                    t2.state_time > t.state_time and
                    t2.state <> t.state
             ) as next_state_time
      from atable t 
     ) t
group by process_id, state;
```

You can add the appropriate `where` clause to gets states only between certain times.

Comment: Unfortunately this query is not correct. I tried it on this table. Critical time should be 400 sec. After using this query it showed me 720sec...